# How do I write a ">" into a txt file with batch?

Tags: html, batch-file

I need to write an html document from a batch file and this document contains the ">" character. When I try to write a ">" character to a file though, it cuts off and doesn't write.

Example -

```
Echo <HTML> > HtmlDoc.html
```

The output here to the file would be

```
<HTML
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Here is what I have to write to an html document -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters:

```
echo ^<html^> > HtmlDoc.html
```

For more information about escapes in batch scripting, read http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Comment: With this the file has `"<html>"` in it.